# Why is the order of the parameters reversed when applying parameter decorators?

Tags: typescript, parameters, decorator

*<sup>A.S.: This question is **not** about [Decorator Composition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-composition). The paragraph [Decorator Evaluation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-evaluation), addresses the question but does not answer it.</sup>*

I have the following code:

```
const decorate = (log: string): ParameterDecorator => () => {
    console.log(log)
}

class Thing {
    constructor(
        @decorate('Outer first')
        @decorate('Inner first')
        c0: string,

        @decorate('Outer second')
        @decorate('Inner second')
        c1: string,
    ) {
        console.log(c0)
        console.log(c1)
    }
}

new Thing('Hello!', 'World!')
```

*[Try it (extended)](https://tsplay.dev/N9YoqN).*

In the above code snippet, all parameters are decorated. The order of logs is:

```
Inner second
Outer second

Inner first
Outer first

Hello!
World!
```

I can understand [why `"Inner …"` comes before `"Outer …"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-composition). But why does `"… second"` come before `"… first"`? In other words, **why do the logs for the second constructor parameter come before the logs for the first one?**

Comment: Assuming this is pre version 5 TS, that's just how it is compiled to - a "reverse" loop.

Comment: @katniss I doubt that the maintainers just felt like using a reverse loop, I think they understand that the order of execution has a big impact on the result in imperative languages. You think that's the case?

Comment: Look at the compiled output. That's literally what it is. I don't know why but the result is a reversed loop.

Comment: Oh, I can figure that part myself, thank you. But that's not what I'm asking about. I'm asking about why is the loop reversed in the first place. In other words, the rationale behind reversing the outer/inner order is function composition: (f*g)(x) -> f(g(x)), so g(…) comes first, and then f(…). I'm asking the same question but about a different phenomenon.